# how to select from two not joined tables in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have two tables that have no common column. But there is relation. I have table1, table2. table 1 is as follows:

```
t1.ID | t1.Name | t1.Number
```

Where Name is unique value.

table2 is as follows:

```
t2.ID | t2.Number1 | t2.Number2 | t2.Country
```

My query is as follows:

```
select t1.Name, t1.Number, t2.country
from db.t1, db.t2
where t1.Number between t2.Number1 AND t2.Number2
```

What is happening as a result from the query is that I get each record twice. But, when I add:

```
group by t1.Name
```

I get the correct result (each record once). I do not want to use group by. How to make correct query and do I get the same record twice without group by ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `DISTINCT` :

```
SELECT DISTINCT 1.Name, t1.Number, t2.country
FROM db.t1, db.t2
WHERE t1.Number BETWEEN t2.Number1 AND t2.Number2
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be at least one column that is common to both of the tables. Else you 'll get duplicate values only.

At least to my knowledge that is the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.Name ,t1.Number from t1
union
select t2.Number1 ,t2.Number2 from t2
```

You can use union in this case.

Comment: Just keep in mind that select statement in both the table should be of same count.